# NSSortDescriptor with first name and last name,or with either first name or last name?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, nssortdescriptor

I am doing sorting of an contact info array,it's working fine when I entered first name and last for particular contact,but it's not working fine when any of it is missing,

For Ex: if I enter first name John and last name mickey ,then it gives proper sorting,but if I enter only mickey then it comes at last in # section in UITableview.,so what I need to do here in this type of case.

My code is as below,

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorFirstName = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)] autorelease];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptorLastName = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(localizedStandardCompare:)] autorelease];

NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:sortDescriptorFirstName,sortDescriptorLastName,nil];

if(favFlag){
    favContacts = [[contactsData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] mutableCopy];
    [self setListContent:favContacts];
}
else {
    contacts = [[contactsData sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors] mutableCopy];
    [self setListContent:contacts];
}

[contactTableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have [custom criteria](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Articles/Arrays.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000132-SW7), you can use comparator blocks instead of descriptors. For example, you can use [`sortedArrayUsingComparator`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator%3a):

```
contacts = [contactsData sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id obj1, id obj2) {
    NSString *sortName1 = [self sortNameWithFirst:[obj1 objectForKey:@"firstName"]
                                             last:[obj1 objectForKey:@"lastName"]];

    NSString *sortName2 = [self sortNameWithFirst:[obj2 objectForKey:@"firstName"]
                                             last:[obj2 objectForKey:@"lastName"]];

    return [sortName1 caseInsensitiveCompare:sortName2];
}];
```

Where I have this little utility method to make it easier to create the "sort name", my term for the string by which I'm ultimately going to sort:

```
- (NSString *)sortNameWithFirst:(NSString *)firstName last:(NSString *)lastName
{
    if (firstName && lastName)
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
    if (firstName)
        return firstName;
    if (lastName)
        return lastName;
    return nil;
}
```

This code takes this list:

```
NSArray *contactsData = @[
    @{@"firstName":@"Rob", @"lastName":@"Zimmer"},
    @{@"firstName":@"Sting"},
    @{@"firstName":@"Rob", @"lastName":@"Ryan"},
    @{@"firstName":@"Cher"},
    @{@"lastName":@"Smith"}
];
```

And gives me "Cher", "Rob Ryan", "Rob Zimmer", "Smith", and "Sting".

To be honest, I wasn't entirely clear how your wanted to sort it on the basis of your question, but you get the idea. The comparator block of `sortedArrayUsingComparator` gives you the ability to create whatever custom sort criteria you want. It just needs to return one of the [`NSComparisonResult`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparisonResult) values of either `NSOrderedAscending`, `NSOrderedSame`, or `NSOrderedDescending` (which I'm conveniently using [`caseInsensitiveCompare`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/caseInsensitiveCompare%3a) to generate for me). For a list of searching alternatives see the [Sorting](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW12) methods listed in the *NSArray Class Reference.*