# NSFetchedResultsController sort by first name or last name

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am basically trying to achieve [NSSortDescriptor with first name and last name,or with either first name or last name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13873077/nssortdescriptor-with-first-name-and-last-name-or-with-either-first-name-or-last) but with an NSFetchedResultsController. I am reading records from the address book and want to display them just like the Address Book does.

The records will be sorted into sections based on first letter of last name. If there isn't a last name it will sort by first name and if there isn't a first name it will sort by company.

Currently I have

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // read the contact list
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [Contact MR_entityDescriptionInContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // sort the results by last name then by first name
    NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"lastName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    NSSortDescriptor *sort2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstName" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sort1, sort2]];

    // Fetch all the contacts and group them by the firstLetter in the last name. We defined this method in the CoreData/Human/Contact.h file
    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:[NSManagedObjectContext MR_defaultContext] sectionNameKeyPath:@"firstLetter" cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Which sorts by last name and then first name. How would I alter this to return the wanted results listed above?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an instance method on `Contact` that has that logic:

```
- (NSString *)sortKey
{
    if(self.lastName) {
        return [self.lastName substringToIndex:1];
    }

    if(self.firstName) {
        return [self.firstName substringToIndex:1];
    }

    return [self.companyName substringToIndex:1];
}
```

Then just have one `NSSortDescriptor` that uses the key `sortKey`

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing for **firstLetter** in the sections. However when I do it like this I get an error `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath firstLetter not found in entity <NSSQLEntity Contact id=1>'` and the code is `NSSortDescriptor *sort1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"firstLetter" ascending:YES selector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)];`

Comment: @Bot Try adding `firstLetter` in your schema as a String property, but just overriding the getter.

Comment: This stops the error but now it returns everything without a section because the firstLetter property is empty. Even though I am using the same code you have but with "firstLetter" instead of "sortKey" in my Contact.m file

Comment: I'm using mogenerator so this is probably causing the override to not take place

Comment: I found a possible solution but it may not be the best. When I am adding the records to core data I am running the firstLetter method and storing that in core data under 'firstLetter' then running the sort based on that.

Comment: You cannot use a transient property for sorting. It must be a modeled persistent property. Use KVO to calculate the sorting value when it's dependancies change, and persist the computed value.