# Nsfetchrequest to sort first Name, Last name even if one is missing

Tags: xcode, ios9

I tried to look for a better way ([Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25294513/nsfetchedresultscontroller-sort-by-first-name-or-last-name)) of executing a fetch request (core data) that will sort First Name, Last name in an imported contacts DB. the problem is when one of these fields is missing, it either goes to the top or goes to the bottom (Depending on sort order)...  is there a way to sort this properly (just like in the contacts app) that will not entail me to modify my existing core data schema?